# linking to table and returning value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

i am trying to query a table and return a value if the conditions are met.

schedule model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :result
  attr_accessible :result_id
end
```

results model

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :schedule
  attr_accessible :against, :for, :schedule_id
end
```

schedules.haml

```
- if schedule.result
  Result
- else
  No Result
```

all im getting is **No Result**, even though i know there is results loaded for the scheduling id

any help would be great thanks

Comment: Is the above sample from your schedules.haml formatted correctly?  HAML relies on indentation.  The "- else" should be aligned with the "- if".

Comment: yes its formatted correctly, all im getting is the No Result for everyone item which isnt correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this site:

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/3096503536/how-to-check-if-objects-or-relations-exist

You may want to try something like

```
schedule.result.any?
```

Also, try:

```
raise schedule.result.to_yaml
```

to see exactly what is returned by this statement

Comment: used `= schedule.results.present?` and got true where i expected, but now how come when i query i.e. schedule.results.for it doesnt return a result ?

Comment: `schedule.result` (not plural) should return a schedule object. However, I'm not familiar with the .for method

Comment: for is an object within my schedule model

Comment: doing that i get `undefined method `result' for #<Schedule:0xa4333fc>`

Comment: You could always try `Result.find(schedule.result_id).for` although this isn't optimal